# Proper usage of вони in a sentence

Tags: from-english, граматика, займенники

I have learned "they" is "вони" in Ukrainian, but what if I want to say "they are"? Do I have to change anything? For example, in the following sentences, I do not understand how 'they' is made to become 'they are' according to the chosen word after вони.

1. "вони тако́ж там" | "**They are** also there" |

(також has the meaning 'also' and in this case appears to change the usage of вони into 'they are'.)

2. "вони́ ще надво́рі" | `"**They are** still out" |

(ще has the meaning 'more' and once again appears to change the usage of вони into 'they are'.)

Are my translations correct? I am looking for further clarification.

Comment: Related: [conventions for the omission of verb **є**](/q/260/585)

Comment: Ukrainian also [has old form](http://chak-chy-pravylno-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/ye) _(ukr)_ of _бути_ for present time: _I am_ — _я єсмь_, _you are_ — _ти еси_, _is_ — _єсть_, _You are_ — _ви єсте_, _they are_ — _вони суть_. Today old form _єсть_ also can be as _є_: _я єсть_, _ти єсть_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

English and Ukrainian are somewhat opposite for conjugation of verbs in present indefinite.

```
P-n \ N-r  Singular          Plural
1-st       (I) see           (we) see
2-nd       (you) see         (you) see
3-rd       (he/she/it) sees  (they) see

P-n \ N-r  Singular          Plural
1-st       (I) am            (we) are
2-nd       (you) are         (you) are
3-rd       (he/she/it) is    (they) are
```

In English most of verbs have only two forms for present indefinite (*see* and *sees*); the notable exception is the verb *to be*, which has 4 forms.

In Ukrainian most of verbs have 6 forms for present indefinite; the notable exception is the Ukrainian equivalent of the verb *to be*, which has a single form.

```
P-n \ N-r  Singular            Plural
1-st       (I) бачу            (we) бачимо
2-nd       (you) бачиш         (you) бачите
3-rd       (he/she/it) бачить  (they) бачать

P-n \ N-r  Singular            Plural
1-st       (I) є               (we) є
2-nd       (you) є             (you) є
3-rd       (he/she/it) є       (they) є
```

*To be* in present indefinite not only has a single form (unlike most of other  verbs), but also usually **is omitted** from the sentence.

You're absolutely right about translations, but absolutely wrong about explanations. Neither the word *also*, nor the word *still* change the meaning of the word *вони*. Everything is much simpler: absence of verbs in a sentence makes it (the sentence) to be interpreted as there's somewhere an omitted *є* in it. (If Google Translate made you to think that words *also* or *still* matter for interpreting *вони* — never mind, it may be just the way Google Translate works, but not the way the Ukrainian language works.)

In many of the cases when *є* is usually omitted, you're still allowed to put it. But putting it may change the meaning of the sentence a bit: sometimes it would introduce emphasis like putting unnecessary *do* into positive sentences in English (*I want it* vs. *I do(!) want it*), sometimes it would emphasize the fact of existence of something over its location, sometimes it would just make the sentence to sound unnaturally. In sentences describing physical location of something, *є* is almost never used (if for some reason you want to put a verb there, it's better to put *перебуває* "is located" than *є*).

Also please note that everything I've said about omitting *є* above is related to present indefinite. In continuous tenses, we also don't use *є*, but the reason is quite different: we simply build continuous tenses in other way (that's not just about omitting an unneeded word anymore). In the past and future indefinite we still use equivalents of *to be* (*був/була/було/були* for past and *буду/будемо/будеш/будете/буде/будуть* for future).

See also: [Conventions for the omission of verb `Є`](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/260)